# Regex acting different in console compared to ISE

Tags: regex, powershell

I ran into a strange behavior while creating an 'interactive' PS script.
When started, the script needs information that is requested from the user. I'm using regex to evaluate the result, but one of them just fails:

```
$a = ""
while (!$a)
{
    Write-Host "`nSome text to instruct the user:"
    $Global:a = Read-Host
    if($a -notmatch "a1[a-z,A-Z]{6}$")
    {
        Write-Host "no match!"
    }
    else {Write-Host "match"}
    }
```

The program waits for a string that begins with 'a1' followed by 6 letters.

When I run this snippet from ISE it works as it should. Providing with the test value a1szvite it returns 'match', nevertheless when I save this as a stand alone script and run it in a normal PowerShell windows it returns 'no match!', and keeps asking for another value which indicates that `$a` is not written with the data for some reason.

All the other regexes work like a charm I'm a bit confused as to what is the matter here. How could the same lines of code with the same feeding value return a different result?

I really think that this is some little mistake from me, I just don't recognized where it is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _The program wait a string that begins with 'a1' followed by 6 letter._. That is not exactly true. Your regex will match when it ends with that. You need the start of line anchor as well. `"^a1[a-z,A-Z]{6}$"`. Perhaps your test cases were matching by accident.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't quite sure what $ and ^ can be used for but now its clear! Thanks for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this and get the same results as you. To help explain my findings I added the following lines to your script.

```
write-host "$a" -ForegroundColor Yellow
write-host "$Global:a" -ForegroundColor Red
```

`$global:a` and `$a` are different variables when the script is being run outside of the ISE. As [Frode F. mentions in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840524/regex-acting-different-in-console-compared-to-iso/36842084?noredirect=1#comment61262442_36842084) the script has its own scope so `$a` is local to the script. The line where you gather used input you are defining another variable in the global scope called `$a`

When I run your script outside of ISE I only get the red text which tells me your `-notmatch` is checking against the original null value of `$a`. Which proves the scope issue.

Remove to scope modifier off the line `$Global:a = Read-Host` and change it to just `$a = Read-Host`. This way all line are referencing the same variable.

---

Side note: I would update your regex string to `^a1[a-z]{6}$` the match operators and most others are not case sensitive so that will match upper and lowercase alike. Also you mention that the string has to start with a1 so using the start of line anchor would enforce that.

Comment: When you run a ex. unsaved script in ISE you can see that ISE writes the code line by line in the embedded powershell console which would make the variables global. When you execute a saved script, it's called like `.\script.ps1` which meakes `$a = ..` a variable in the script-scope.

Comment: @FrodeF. Ah yes. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: The weird thing is that when ISE executes a script, it doesn't use dot-sourcing but the variables are still modified in the global scope, however when you run it in a normal powershell console, it will use the script scope. One of the funky features of ISE, but I guess it emulates writing all the lines like if it was an unsaved file, but replaces the lines with a script-call to keep it clean.

Comment: @FrodeF I removed the global modifier and now it seems working, but it raises an other question: Why the other similar snippet worked? Than I realized that they actually aren't working. Using the global the script works in the ISE but fails outside of it. Without the global the script works outside the ISE but cannot access the globally defined variables. The vars are defined at the begin of the script and they should be written inside of a function. I'll try to pass the variable to the function instead of just try to write them.

Comment: The solution was the script scope instead of global.

Comment: What function are you talking about? There is no function  in the code you have above? @secthor

Comment: That is right. I wasn't provide the entire script only the part that seemed to be not working.